# Converting self signed certificate to p7 with full certificate chain

Tags: ssl-certificate

I am trying to create a self sign certificate and then convert that certificate to P7 format with full certificate chain.
I am able to create a self sign certificate, but not sure how to convert this to p7 with full certificate chain

Following are the steps which i have taken to create a self signed certificate

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fiserv\server.crt -inkey fiserv\server.key -out fiserv\server.p12
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You say you want to have P7 format (I assume you mean PKCS#7 / P7B), but you are using the `pkcs12` command (for PKCS#12 / PFX format). Try the `crl2pkcs7` command instead:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile fiserv\server.crt -out fiserv\server.p7b -certfile path\to\CA\CACert.cer
```

I recommend reading https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html, as it explains the different formats and conversions between them. Using that web page I have come up with this quick "cheat sheet" for the conversions that I frequently use:

- **DER** to **PEM**: `openssl x509 -inform DER -in cert.der -out cert.pem`
- **PEM** to **DER**: `openssl x509 -outform DER -in cert.pem -out cert.der`
- **PEM** to **PKCS#12 / PFX**: `openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -out cert.p12`
- **PEM** to **PKCS#7 / P7B**: `openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile cert.pem -out cert.p7b`
- **PKCS#12** to **PEM**: `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem`
- **PKCS#7 / P7B** to **PEM**: `openssl pkcs7 -in cert.p7b -print_certs -out cert.pem`